# Fetching ical url

Tags: javascript, fetch, icalendar

I'm trying to retrieve a content from the specific ical url using ical npm.
I'm testing this code on the client side. There are a few icals that I've managed to fetch. But this one and several others I didn't.
It works great on POSTMAN.

My code is:

```
const ical = require('ical');
ical.fromURL('https://admin.vrbo.com/icalendar/5d19afbfbf144218a3c76eacf76267c6.ics', {mode: 'cors'}, (err, data) => {
        console.log(err)
});
```

The error I get:

```
Error: Invalid value for opts.mode
    at new push../node_modules/stream-http/lib/request.js.module.exports (request.js:58)
    at Object.push../node_modules/stream-http/index.js.http.request (index.js:30)
    at Object.push../node_modules/https-browserify/index.js.https.request (index.js:13)
    at Request.push../node_modules/request/request.js.Request.start (request.js:829)
    at Request.push../node_modules/request/request.js.Request.end (request.js:1639)
    at end (request.js:628)
    at request.js:644
    at run (setImmediate.js:48)
    at runIfPresent (setImmediate.js:83)
    at onGlobalMessage (setImmediate.js:125)
```

Pleas tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to make this code work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is, that you are trying to pass an invalid option (`{mode: 'cors'}`). `ical.fromURL(...)` will pass the `options` argument as it is to `request` (See [Line 8](https://github.com/peterbraden/ical.js/blob/52c1d1c2b1ea3a74fb9254f0fc3f7a98503d3886/node-ical.js)). I've checked the source of [request](https://github.com/request/request), but did not find any option with the name `mode` (Maybe you are mixing it up with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), because there is an option called `mode`), so in my opinion, that is also the reason, why you are getting the error (But I'm not sure why it worked out for you, to fetch some other calendars). You can check the [full list of possible options](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) by yourself.

Comment: what error do you get when you pass `{}`, instead of `{mode: 'cors'}` ?